# Line breaks with theme settings textarea

Tags: 7, forms

I'm using the following to get a form field in the theme settings page

```
function theme_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
   $form['foo_example'] = array(
   '#type'          => 'textarea',
   '#title'         => t('Widget'),
   '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('foo_example'),
   '#description'   => t("Place this text in the widget spot on your site."),
 );
}
```

The problem is when I output the result in my theme file with this:

```
$foo_example = theme_get_setting('foo_example');                             
print render($foo_example);
```

It doesn't respect the line break and puts it all in one p tag. I'd like it to respect the line break and put each line in a p tag if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use ["text_format" type](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#text_format).

```
 $form['foo_example'] = array(
   '#type'          => 'text_format',
   '#title'         => t('Widget'),
   '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('foo_example'),
   '#description'   => t("Place this text in the widget spot on your site."),
   '#format' => null, //I think "null" saves the default text format of your website. If you want to see your changes you must put a dynamic value.
 );
}
```

NOTA BENE: the values saved by this type of textarea, is an array with "value" and "format" keys:

```
$var_saved = array(
'value'=> 'something', 
'format' => 'full_html', //could be filtered_html, plain_text or any custom text format you've created.
);

//in your field definition
'#default_value' => $var_saved['value'],
'#format' => $var_saved['format'],
```

I didn't test it for your case, but choosing the right format, will normally output the text with respect of the rules chosen for that format type.

If I understood well your problem...